# NativeScript, Play sound mixed in with other app playing in background

Tags: ios, audio, webview, nativescript

How do I make my Tags NativeScript app play sound mixed in with other app playing in background?

I have looked everywhere, please help!

Comment: You will have to set the AVAudioSession Category to [AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryambient). If you are using the audio plugin, you will have to override [these lines](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio/blob/06fca1988426dbf70ec4dc90c59767106c9281ad/src/ios/player.ts#L163-L170).

Comment: aa sweet! Can you show me how I do override this lines? Please

Comment: I guess, you will have to take a fork and make it as an option that could be passed within `AudioPlayerOptions`.

Comment: oh.. now you are talking above my head.. haha. Can you help me with this?

Comment: i am so lost mate.. please help in what i need to do more exactly

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to do it for you, not finding time at the moment. But all you have to do is to take a fork, clone it, modify those lines I mentioned above to support `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` category. Use the npm commands in the `src/package.json` to build the plugin and link it to your app.

Comment: Is there a way to pay you for the work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187063/discussion-between-manoj-and-user2673664).

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this. Add this lines in app.js

```
  var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();
  try {
    audioSession.setCategoryError(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient);
    audioSession.setActiveError(true);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("setting audioSession category failed");
  }
```